# The type initializer for 'Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client' threw an exception

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been working on a project in which we are using **AWS S3** to store files, all this using **AWS SDK** for **Visual Studio .NET**, when I realized the deployment of the application on a production server access to AWS S3 fail in every attempts to create / delete files, thrown exception is not very explicit so do not know how to solve the problem.

This is my C# code

```
// Create a client
AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client();
// Create a GetObject request
GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
{
   BucketName = MyBucketS3,
   Key = MyFileKeyS3
};
```

When the application Executes

```
Amazon S3 Client client = new AmazonS3Client();
```

An Exception is Thrown

```
    `The type initializer for 'Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client' threw an exception`.
```

My keys are correct, from my local environment they are working perfectly.
This is a fragment of my web.config file(with Dummy keys):

```
 <add key="AWSAccessKey" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
 <add key="AWSSecretKey" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't address your AmazonS3Client issue in particular, but I'd like to note that I was seeing a very similar type initializer exception when trying to use AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell. In particular, when trying to run

```
import-module "C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell\AWSPowerShell\AWSPowerShell.psd1"
```

and/or when trying to execute a command like

```
Get-S3Bucket
```

then I'd get a type initializer error.

In my case, the fix was to install version 3.5 of the .NET framework in addition to the version 4.5 that I already had installed. (Thanks, Microsoft and Amazon, for providing such a helpful error message.)

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem when using *the sample code for AWS "CognitoSync"* from AWS .net in Github.

Solved the problem by upgrading the `Nuget` package for `cognito` and `AWS core` to the latest version 
`[AWSSDK.CongnitoIdentity v3.3.1.2, AWSSDK.CognitoSync v3.3.1.6, AWSSDK.SecurityToken v3.3.0.9 and AWSSDK.Core to v3.3.8 ]`.

Guess this issue happens due to the different variable structure resulting in invalid access to the data.